# Flutter Dismissible not working anymore, but code looks correct

Tags: flutter, dart, dismissible

I've been writing an application which requires the users to be able to dismiss objects from a list. I had this all working, and then it suddenly stopped working, and I have no idea why.

I've commented out almost all of the code - this is all that remains, but the dismissible STILL doesn't work (although it worked fine previously!!!!):

```
//... setup stuff not relevant to question

class _Screen extends State<Screen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: profileCard(true),
    );

Dismissible profileCard(bool centre) {

    return Dismissible(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      background: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      secondaryBackground: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.purple,
      ),
    );

//....
```

The swipe action just refuses to work *AT ALL*, and I'm tearing my hair out as to why. Any Flutter experts out there able to help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: I added your code to my sample project and it does swipe and dismiss. It looks abit odd, but the dismissing works. Will need more info to help any more.

Comment: Thanks, @BenediktJSchlegel - but other than that, the only other bit of code in the file at the moment is a timer which sets a boolean. Everything else is commented out.

Comment: No error messages shown?
Try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` once before running your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the error came from running a timer at every 44 millisecond intervals and setting a boolean in there.

Not sure why that was, as the boolean in question was unrelated to the dismissible.

Thanks for your help, folks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Benedikt J Schlegel, Your code works for `Dismissible` .

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Screen(),
  ));
}

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  Dismissible profileCard(bool centre) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      background: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      secondaryBackground: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        color: Colors.purple,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Dismissible'),
        ),
        body: profileCard(true));
  }
}
```